# Bridge Assurance with vPC on port type network

Tags: spanning-tree, ieee-802.1ax, vpc

I'm running two Nexus 3048 switches as network core and I got an issue when linking another switch (specifically a 2960-X) on the vPC links. Consider the scenario:

```
+-------+   +-------+ 
| NX #1 |===| NX #2 |
+-------+   +-------+
       |     |
      +-------+
      | 2960X |
      +-------+
```

On the 2960X there's a Port-Channel configured in active mode. When setting the interfaces on nexus as: `spanning-tree port type network`, Bridge Assurance comes in action and blocks the ports.

At this moment I'm running it on "normal type" so it won't disable the links.

I've read something over the web that I can't use `spanning-tree port type network` but I don't know if my mind is playing on me or if it's exactly the case. If yes, why I can't do this? Network ports shouldn't be used for inter switch connections?

Thanks,

Additional Configurations for the exemplify the issue:

NX #1

```
interface port-channel9
  description Downlink TCC6-1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 256
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 146,172,256,666
  spanning-tree port type normal
  spanning-tree guard root
  vpc 9

interface Ethernet1/9
  description Downlink TCC6-1 #1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 256
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 146,172,256,666
  channel-group 9 mode active
  no shutdown
```

NX #2

```
interface port-channel9
  description Downlink TCC6-1
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 256
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 146,172,256,666
  spanning-tree port type normal
  spanning-tree guard root
  vpc 9

interface Ethernet1/9
  description Downlink TCC6-1 #2
  switchport mode trunk
  switchport trunk native vlan 256
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 146,172,256,666
  channel-group 9 mode active
  no shutdown
```

2960-X

```
interface Port-channel1
 description Uplink Core-CC
 switchport trunk native vlan 256
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 146,172,256,666
 switchport mode trunk
 ip arp inspection trust
 ip dhcp snooping trust
end

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/47
 description Uplink Core-CC (Port Channel Interface #1)
 switchport trunk native vlan 256
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 146,172,256,666
 switchport mode trunk
 ip arp inspection trust
 channel-group 1 mode active
 ip dhcp snooping trust
end

interface GigabitEthernet1/0/48
 description Uplink Core-CC (Port Channel Interface #2)
 switchport trunk native vlan 256
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 146,172,256,666
 switchport mode trunk
 ip arp inspection trust
 channel-group 1 mode active
 ip dhcp snooping trust
end
```

Comment: As a side note, you are missing "vpc 9" underneath the Po9 config on NX#1.

Comment: Ops, was a copy and paste error. Fixed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spanning-tree port type network activates bridge assurance on the link.  Since the 2960X doesn't support bridge assurance, you can't run this link as port type network.  Just run it in normal mode.  About the only place you want to run port type network is on the vPC peer-link where it is enabled by default.

From the best practices design guide:

- Bridge Assurance is enabled by default when configuring vPC peer-link. Do not disable it on vPC peer-link
- It is not necessary to enable Bridge Assurance on vPC (Bridge Assurance is enabled when the vPC member port is defined as spanning-tree port type network)
- Configure vPC member port as spanning-tree port type normal (so not using Bridge Assurance on the link)